# How do embedded databases work in java when going from Netbeans to IntelliJ?

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, netbeans, derby

I'm wondering how embedded databases work. Let's say I'm using derby databases on Netbeans for java IDE and everything works. If I zip up all the project files and send it to another user who's using IntelliJ as their IDE and they open the file can they run it straight off the bat (assuming JDK/java version etc are the same) or do they have to install things as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything can be embedded into a single package, such as a zip.

The typical deployment model is *not* to distribute your application as source code and project files, requiring your user to build the application in their IDE, but rather to distribute your application as bytecode class files, fully compiled, so your user can just copy the application package onto their system and run it directly.

When you do this, all they have to provide is a copy of the Java Runtime Environment.

Here's some docs on the subject: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/devguide/cdevdeploy855368.html

The Derby documentation also contains a number of sample programs and tutorials, and I highly recommend doing the tutorials as they will help you understand the overall process: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html